# how show view page with JSF 2.2

Tags: jsf-2, jsf-2.2

Please, I need your help with my code. Trying to make a query for an invoice on another page. On the page(FacturaShow.xhtml) shows null. But in the console comes the result with System out.

facturaBean.java

```
public String outcome() {

    FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    this.visualizarfact = Integer.parseInt(getNumeroFacturaParam(fc));
    System.out.println("Factura : " + this.visualizarfact);
    return "FacturaShow.jsf";
}

//get value from "f:param"
public String getNumeroFacturaParam(FacesContext fc) {

    Map<String, String> params = fc.getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();
    return params.get("numerofactura");

}
```

FacturaIndex.xhtml is the page where it shows an invoice list where the invoice is to be used to print, cancel, display. Near the end of the code, you will find the commandLink to call the FacturaShow with id="reportefactura6".

```
                <h:form id="formMostraFacturas">
                <p:dataTable id="tablaFacturas" paginator="true" paginatorPosition="top" rows="20"
                             var="ft" value="#{facturaBean.listaFacturas}" emptyMessage="No hay datos de Facturas"
                             paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
                             rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15">
                    <p:column headerText="NRO." style="width: 40px">
                        <h:outputText value="#{ft.numeroFactura}" style="display:block;text-align: center"/>
                    </p:column>

                    <p:column headerText="EMPRESA" style="width: 500px">
                        <h:outputText value="#{ft.cliente.nombreCliente}"/>
                    </p:column>                        

                    <p:column headerText="RUC" style="width: 100px" >
                        <h:outputText value="#{ft.cliente.rucCliente}" style="display:block;text-align: center"/>
                    </p:column>

                    <p:column headerText="MONEDA" style="width: 70px" >
                        <h:outputText value="#{ft.moneda.simboloMoneda}" style="display:block;text-align: center"/>
                    </p:column>

                    <p:column headerText="TOTAL" style="width: 100px">
                        <h:outputText value="#{ft.totalVenta+(ft.totalVenta*0.18)}" style="display:block;text-align: right">
                            <f:convertNumber pattern="###,###,##0.00" type="currency"
                                             locale="en_US" />
                        </h:outputText>
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="IMPRIMIR" style="width: 70px; text-align: center">
                        <h:commandLink id="reportefactura1" target="_blank" actionListener="#{facturaBean.pedirFactura(ft.numeroFactura, ft.totalVenta, ft.moneda.simboloMoneda)}"                                           
                                       title="Visualizar Factura PDF" action="#{facturaBean.verFacturaNavegadorPDF()}" >
                            <h:graphicImage value="/resources/Imagenes/impresora.png" width="20" height="20"/>
                        </h:commandLink>
                        <h:outputText value=" "/>
                        <h:commandLink id="reportefactura2" target="_blank" actionListener="#{facturaBean.pedirFactura(ft.numeroFactura, ft.totalVenta, ft.moneda.simboloMoneda)}"                                           
                                       title="Descargar Factura en PDF" action="#{facturaBean.verFacturaExportadaPDF()}" >
                            <h:graphicImage value="/resources/Imagenes/descargapdf.png" width="20" height="20"/>
                        </h:commandLink>
                        <h:outputText value=" "/>
                        <h:commandLink id="reportefactura3" target="_blank" actionListener="#{facturaBean.pedirFactura(ft.numeroFactura, ft.totalVenta, ft.moneda.simboloMoneda)}"                                           
                                       title="Imprimir en la impresora Matricial" action="#{facturaBean.verFacturaMatrixNavegadorPDF()}" >
                            <h:graphicImage value="/resources/Imagenes/impresoramatricial.png" width="20" height="20"/>
                        </h:commandLink>
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="OPCIONES" style="width: 70px; text-align: center">
                        <p:commandLink id="reportefactura4"
                                       oncomplete="PF('dialogVerFactura').show();"
                                       update=":formVerFactura" >
                            <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{facturaBean.factura}" value="#{ft}"/>
                            <h:graphicImage value="/resources/Imagenes/ojo.png" width="20" height="20"/>
                        </p:commandLink>
                        <p:outputLabel value=" "/>
                        <p:commandLink id="reportefactura5"
                                       target="_blank" title="Anular Factura" >
                            <h:graphicImage value="/resources/Imagenes/anular.png" width="20" height="20"/>
                        </p:commandLink>

                        <h:commandLink id="reportefactura6" action="#{facturaBean.outcome}">
                            <f:param name="numerofactura" value="#{ft.numeroFactura}"/>
                            <h:graphicImage value="/resources/Imagenes/ojo.png" width="20" height="20"/>
                        </h:commandLink>
                    </p:column>
                </p:dataTable>
            </h:form>
```

FacturaShow.xhtml is the page where the invoice information is displayed.

```
    <h:body>

    <ui:composition template="./../../Plantilla/Plantilla.xhtml">

        <ui:define name="content">
            <p><h2>Visualizando la Factura</h2></p>
            <h:form>
                <h:outputText value="f1: #{facturaBean.visualizarfact}"/>
                <p></p>
                <h:outputText value="f2: #{facturaBean.visualizarfact}"/>
                <p></p>
                <h:outputFormat value="Invoice : {1}">
                    <f:param value="#{facturaBean.visualizarfact}"/>
                    <f:param value="#{facturaBean.visualizarfact}"/>
                </h:outputFormat>
            </h:form>
        </ui:define>

    </ui:composition>

</h:body>
```

I am posting the image where the null appears.
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/765IV.png)

Comment: So it works with a jsf 2 version nut not jsf 2.2? Please create a [mcve]

Comment: What is a scope of `facturaBean` bean?

Comment: The facturaBean file is the controller where the invoice is issued, the invoice list. In this file I use hibernate.

Comment: I have Netbeans 8.2 that already comes jsf 2.2 by default.

Comment: You have an example where I can call an invoice number on a page.

Comment: I solved this problem. I had change -@ViewScoped to -@SessionScoped. Thank you.